# RelativeLayout, GestureOverlayView and SurfaceView Which Widget to be used?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-relativelayout, surfaceview

[image: App ScreenShot]

On viewing the attachment Screenshot

3 things to be handled,

1. Tshirt - ImageView/Bitmap
2. Picture inside TShirt (From Camera/gallery) - ImageView/Bitmap (Here I have succeeded in getting the Image Pinch zoom drag etc)
3. Tshirt Text with external fonts - Converted to Bitmap (Here I have succeeded in using External fonts using Freetype and getting the Image Pinch zoom drag etc)

Need to save the content of the three and retrieve resume or restart activity

Here the Buttons - Style (In seperate Left View), Tools (In seperate Right View), Photo(New View), Text, Color, Add to cart and all this to be displayed on the overlay of the Tshirt in Z axis.

1st Idea : If we use Relative Layout for that we cannot achieve saving the current state of Tshirt.

2nd Idea : If we use SurfaceView, SurfaceHolder.Callback and develop as a game type and Using the thread get noticed with every activity is the possible. But I was struck in working with SurfaceView Thread.

3rd Idea : If we can have 2 seperate views for Work area and buttons then we can invalidate all views and bring the view which is affected with ontouch in front. But problem with saving the work area.

4th Idea : If we can use the same 2 seperate view concept and in the workarea view If we use the GestureOverlayview and bring bitmaps into this view just by addView concept since gestureoverlayview just like a framelayout, it is achievable. Here we can have this view in seperate class and with a constructor we can get the parameters for the saved Tshirt designs if we need to resume or restart the activity to redesign. So I will have a list of designs in my cart where I can redesign with a single click, where the Activity or saved instance should resume or restart to this editing state.

I am trying if any one could work out. If you have any other ways to achieve from your perspective, Please Help me in getting the context alone so I could work on it and achieve.